# My colleagues earn twice more than I do. How can I approach my employer for a fair salary?

Tags: professionalism, human-resources

When I got my new job at a new employer, I was a trainee and earned 50% less than my current salary.

I can currently estimate that my colleagues earn twice if not more than I do. Our job titles/responsibilities are exactly the same. Our qualifications are exactly the same. However they have one year or so more experience than me.

Should I approach my employer and ask for a fair salary? If I do approach, how should I prepare, and what points should I make to be successful?

Comment: Hey Eric, if that doesn't answer your question, please [edit] this one to include more details to differentiate it.

Comment: @jmort253 - I think the circumstances are different. The OP in the linked question believes he's earned a raise by virtue of his natural work progression; OP here is looking toward a raise by virtue of comparison of his pay to his peers; different circumstances. Surely the reason for asking for a raise plays a factor in the kind of answers this question will elicit

Comment: Good point, @kolossus, I edited to expand this a little bit beyond a simple yes/no question. Let's give Eric a chance to look at the other answers first. This will give us all a chance to work together to make sure we get Eric the best answers to his specific problem that aren't just repeats of what's already been said.  I'll also drop a link in [chat] to get others involved.

Comment: Eric, I'm not sure whether or not this question is truly a duplicate, but I definitely think the answers to that other question will be of value to you.

Comment: How much experience do you have in this field? If it's one year, and your colleagues have two years, the pay difference may not be totally unreasonable. But if you have 20 years, and they have 21 and are earning twice as much as you, that's probably very unfair!